# Filter NSDictionary with two keys and result array contain pairs keys-values

Tags: nsmutablearray, key, nsdictionary, nspredicate

Have similar, but not found solution, have a two NSMutables arrays (sublista and subdetail), contains name and telephone of every persons. I construct NSMutableDictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *playas = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:sublista, @"nombre", subdetail, @"telephone", nil];
```

and make a Array:

```
[alldata addObject:playas];
```

Like search in nombre key and result array with pairs nombre and telephone.

CLEARANCES:

Like search in nombre key and result array with pairs nombre and telephone.

the subtitle array its a NSMutableArray that contain names, i.e. "Jose", "john" and subtitle contain telephones "12324", "65746574" etc

The subtitle and subdetail its a NSMutableArray, alldata its a NSMutable array:

.h

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sublista; 
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *subdetail; 
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *alldata;
```

alldata structure its:

```
alldata = (_NSArrayM *) 2key/value pairs   
        >[0] = @"nombre" : @"3239 objects" 
        >>key = (_NSCFConstantString *) @"nombre" 
        >>value = (_NSArrayM *) @"3239 objects" 
        >>>[0] = (_NSCFString *) @"Jose" 
        >>>[1] = (_NSCFString *) @"Jhon" 
        >>>....   
        >[1] = @"telephone" : @"3239 objects" 
        >>key = (_NSCFConstantString *) @"telephone" 
        >>value = (_NSArrayM *) @"3239 objects" 
        >>>[0] = (_NSCFString *) @"1234567" 
        >>>[1] = (_NSCFString *) @"8901234"
        >>>....
```

hope your understood THANKS! –

Comment: Need clarification. The array is supposed to contain what?

Comment: The subtitle array its  a NSMutableArray that contain names, i.e. "Jose", "john" and subtitle contain telephones "12324", "65746574" etc.

Comment: What is the structure of alldata? What do want it to have? What are the sublists and subdetail? What is subtitle? Why did you put them into playas? What happens now that after you addObject to alldata?